# how to increase svg size which is append to the icon tag?

Tags: css, angular, svg

I got an icon as svg. To add them in my angular app: I have created a class like this:

```
.ic-graduation-cap{
    height: 56px;
    display: inline;
    background:url('/assets/img/svg/graduation-cap.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
```

here is the markup of my svg element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.0.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 36 36"
     style="enable-background:new 0 0 36 36;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    
        .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#5533FF;stroke-width:0.6891;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#5533FF;stroke-width:0.6891;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M28.6,15.4H8v13.5c0,0,3.5,3,10,2.9c6.5-0.1,10.5-2.9,10.5-2.9V15.4z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M28.6,13.3H8v13.5c0,0,3.5,3,10,2.9c6.5-0.1,10.5-2.9,10.5-2.9V13.3z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M0.5,15.4l17.4-9.1l17.7,9L18,24.3L0.5,15.4z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M23,12.7l8.6,4.2l0.1,6.6"/>
    <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-48.6867,-25.7866)">
        <path class="st0" d="M80.4,49.3l1.7,3.9h-3.4L80.4,49.3z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now to add this svg icon on my app: I was using an `i` tag:

```
<i *ngIf="isCustomIcon" class="ic-graduation-cap"></i>
```

Unfortunately, my SVG size is not correct. here is the picture, that is what it looks like.

[image] It does not even look bold. it seems so small. How can I increase the SVG size? and let them look as bold?
Can someone please help? the rest two working icons from `i-feather` library

I even tried with the img tag. but it did not help

Comment: What's the markup of graduation-cap.svg and what's the markup of one of the "working" icons?

Comment: @robert-longson I have added the mark-up. the working i con from i-feather library

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to see the SVG to the left to compare. When I look a the "square academic cap" it looks fine (taking up 100% of the viewBox), but compared to the other, a bit flimsy on the stroke-width. And in your screen dump it looks like the icon is displayed smaller (which is strange because it takes up 100 %).

Comment: did you on your case it was working while setting 100% viewBox? May I see your example code, please? if you have any @chrwahl

Comment: @Kazi I'm just viewing your code in a browser window, nothing special. My point is that the content/the path lines almost fill out the entire viewBox (so the box that is 36,36) -- and therefor I guess that there is something different in the CSS between the different icons. But could you include one of the other icons in your question, so that we can compare?